# Can't get max_post_size php variable set in lunar pages

Tags: php, drupal, shared-hosting

I need to increase max post size and upload size for php to use the audio module of drupal. I read this has to be set in php.ini. However I don't think I have access to that file in lunar pages. I also read it can also be set in .htaccess. However it doesn't change anything.

I tried:

php_value post_max_size "40M"
 
php_value upload_max_filesize "40M"

i also tried:

php_value post_max_size 40M
php_value upload_max_filesize 40M

On localhost it says restart webserver. But this is not possible on shared host. Could that be the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer at http://wiki.lunarpages.com/Increase_php.ini_Upload_Limit.

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

It's likely that your shared hosting provider has disabled changing those values locally - for the obvious reason that otherwise, everybody could circumvent the limits as they please, rendering them useless.

(Removed `ini_set` example, as @Pascal says, those limits are enforced before the script is executed.)

You would probably have to talk to your hosting provider if you want to change this.

Comment: The size of uploads is checked / enforced before the script actually starts -- so you cannot change those from a PHP script *(and, trying your code, the values displayed by `phpinfo()` are the ones from `php.ini`, not the ones in `ini_set`)*

Comment: @Pascal true. What was I thinking? :) Cheers.

Comment: Is there any other solutions?

Comment: None except speaking to your hosting provider I think.